# Problem in String camparisson ...!

Tags: iphone

here is my code :

```
NSUInteger f;
  for (f = 0; f < [appDelegate.books count]; f++) {
    check = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:f];

    checkthis = check.LotteryNumber;


        mystring = check.LotteryNumber;
    NSLog(@"Dynamic Value: %@",mystring);
    NSLog(@"Static Value: %@",checkthis);

    if (checkthis == mystring) {
        found = YES;
        break;
    }
    printf("In LOOP");
}
if ( found ) {
    // do found
    NSLog(@"Found");
} else {
    // do not found
    NSLog(@"not Found");
}


    //if (checkthis == mystring) {
```

in above line if i place checkthis on both side , its working , but when i am taking a dynamic value its not working..
i also tried like this

```
if(checthis isEqualToString mystring)
```

same problem here ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you even comparing them if you are assigning the 2 variables to the same value? You need to reformat the post, and it looks like you should be giving us more code from the beginning, because `checkthis = check.LotteryNumber` shouldn't work because you aren't casting it to any NSString.

Answer (score 3):

You're using pointer comparison and not string comparison.

You should be using:

```
if([checkThis isEqualToString:myString]) { ...
```

Comment: looks like you are missing a ']' there :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using comparision by pointer the comparison you made checks memory a ddresses and will only return true if its the same object being compared, you should use [string isEqualToString:otherString] method from  NSString instead

Comment: as i explained in the question i have also tried that..
like this 
if([string1 isEqualToString:string2] 
my first string i static i used like this 
NSString *string1 =@"1234567";
and in string2 i have the value coming from the xml parse...
i checked that value by nslog its same as the string 1 , 
but it doesn't true the condition..

Comment: are they actaully equal tho? NSLog both strings maybe you have an exstra space there, or something of the sort

Comment: Yes ... i used nslog to check that its true or not , but the condition is always true ...:)